# Why is this OpenGL/GLFW code causing my Computer screen to freeze?

Tags: c++, opengl, render, glfw

I am currently making a simple program that uses OpenGL (GLFW) to draw a single square in a window. I am successful in doing so, however after watching the program run for about ten seconds my computer screen freezes and can only be unfrozen by rebooting my machine. My knowledge of how OpenGL works is very limited so I was hoping someone could point out what part of my program is causing the freezing and how I can go about fixing it. Thanks.

main():

```
glfwInit();
GLFWwindow *window=glfwCreateWindow(640,480,"OpenGL",NULL,NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glViewport(0.0f,0.0f,640,480);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,640,480,0,0,1);
glfwSwapInterval(1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
while(true){
    renderSquareTest(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

renderSquareTest(GLFWwindow *window):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(.5f,.5f,.5f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2d(100.0f,100.0f);
glVertex2d(0.0f,100.0f);
glVertex2d(0.0f,0.0f);
glVertex2d(100.0f,0.0f);
glEnd();
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

Comment: You should check if your app have memory leaks. They may cause increasing RAM consumption to the point of system hang.

Comment: All of the code displayed here is basically the entirety of my program. If there is a memory leak it is being caused by what OpenGL does behind the scenes. I have a RAM meter as a desktop widget, and it never goes above 18% while I am running the program.

Comment: the exemple code at http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html checks !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) at the begining of each loop to not try to render if the state becomes incompatible with displaying. you should probably be doing that

Comment: @Julius: That's not what glfwWindowShouldClose does. That function checks a flag that can be set by various events, like clicking the close button, or the program asking for the window to be closed. However the "state becoming incompatible with displaying" is not among that. In Direct3D that may happen, but not OpenGL, which is different in that regard.

Comment: @Julius: I actually had that instead of the while(true) loop. I changed it to while true just because I thought that may have been causing the problem, however it didn't make a difference. That link is one of the two tutorials I was using as references when writing this code.

Comment: Have you figured out the issue to this error? This is bugging me. I've been dealing with it for a week...